# Display all sub site for a site collection SharePoint Online

Tags: javascript, web-part, sub-site, online

Good morning,

I'm using sharepoint online part of Office 365, but my license is business essential. I need to display inside a page all the sub sites of my site collection with 
-Title 
- Link
- Logo Image. 
I can do it neither with content query nor content search Web part because of my licence.
Could someone please help me to solve this problem using javascript with script web part.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a SharePoint Add-in project
2. Select Client Web Part
3. Paste this code below in your `App.js` :

   ```
   function getWebs()
   {
      var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      var web = context.get_web();
      var site = context.get_site(); 
      var rootWeb = web.get_rootWeb();
      var subWebs = rootWeb.get_webs();

      context.load(subWebs, 'Include(Title, ServerRelativeUrl,ParentWeb,Url)');
      context.executeQueryAsync(
       function () {  
            for (var i = 0; i < subWebs.get_count(); i++) {
               var subWeb = subWebs.getItemAtIndex(i);
               var parentWeb = subWeb.get_parentWeb();
               console.log(subWeb.get_title());
               console.log(subWeb.get_serverRelativeUrl());
               console.log(subWeb.get_url());
             }
       },
       function (sender, args) {
          console.log(args.get_message());
       }
      );   
   }
   ```

Comment: Tkx Youssef, but I followed all the steps but I have no result.

Comment: Ok Raise, i update it please try this one.

Comment: thank you very much for you time and help. I've found another solution too.
using the content script editor. see the code link Below.  http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/get-all-subsites-information-using-sharepoint-client-object-model-20709.aspx